# Android kernel for nougat - enable Android Accessory for android auto to work

Tags: android, kernel, accessory

Im trying to build a kernel with Android auto support. The kernel source is stock for oneplus 3 nougat 7.1.1 OOS version 4.5.0.

I need steps to add support for Android auto. I believe I should enable **config_usb_f_acc=y**.

I did that but I'm getting compile time errors:

```
drivers/usb/gadget/g_android.o:(___ksymtab_gpl+acc_ctrlrequest+0x0): multiple definition of `__ksymtab_acc_ctrlrequest'
drivers/usb/gadget/function/built-in.o:(___ksymtab_gpl+acc_ctrlrequest+0x0): first defined here
drivers/usb/gadget/g_android.o: In function `f_midi_disable':
/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/./drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_midi.c:381: multiple definition of `__ksymtab_acc_disconnect'
drivers/usb/gadget/function/built-in.o:/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:436: first defined here
drivers/usb/gadget/g_android.o: In function `acc_ctrlrequest':
/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/./drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:869: multiple definition of `acc_ctrlrequest'
drivers/usb/gadget/function/built-in.o:/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:869: first defined here
drivers/usb/gadget/g_android.o: In function `acc_ctrlrequest_configfs':
/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/./drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:1417: multiple definition of `acc_ctrlrequest_configfs'
drivers/usb/gadget/function/built-in.o:/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:1417: first defined here
drivers/usb/gadget/g_android.o: In function `acc_disconnect':
/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/./drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:1321: multiple definition of `acc_disconnect'
drivers/usb/gadget/function/built-in.o:/home/jesus/oneplus/android_kernel_oneplus_msm89963/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_accessory.c:1321: first defined here
make[3]: *** [drivers/usb/gadget/built-in.o] Error 1
```

Any help regarding this?

The multiple function definition error I've checked and found that there was indeed no multiple definitions. To check that I duplicated the function `acc_ctrlrequest` and renamed it to `acc_ctrlrequest1` and compiled. It's showing the same error for the newly created function. What's does this mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be **in the question post** itself, not linked. Please, [edit] the question post and paste the error message into it. After pasting, you may format the error with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.